# PHP script connecting to Oracle works for Integers but not Strings, the script works in SQL_Developer however

Tags: php, sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

***EDIT***

**Problem Solved:** I had removed a line in my PL/SQL procedure by mistake at some point, enable DBMS output, so it could not send the PHP anything. When testing it in SQL developer I have to connect to my network and the code I use to do that enables DBMS output, so that is why it worked in SQL_Developer and not in PHP.

I feel very silly now that is has come down to a deleted line of code by mistake.

I will leave query below in case anyone has anything similar

---

Smashing my head against a table trying to work out why this doesn't work.

This is connecting to an Oracle database using PHP, creating code in SQL_Developer.

I created a PL/SQL procedure that would take two integers as start and end nodes and spit out some directions, which worked fine and dandy in SQL_Developer and through PHP. The select statement in my PHP was this and returned what I needed.

```
$get_instruc = "Select * FROM TABLE(Navi_Instructions.Get_Navi_Instructions(:start_node,:end_node))";
```

(Integers are binded in using oci_bind_by_name).

I now have a requirement for the integers to be strings, so I have re-written the PL/SQL procedure to accommodate this. My new procedure works perfectly, and when I use the following select statement in SQL_Developer it retrieves the correct data

```
Select * FROM TABLE(Navi_Instructions_Final.Get_Navi_Instructions_Final('Room_101','Room_120'));
```

My next step was to simply put this select statement into PHP, but the PHP select statement refuses to return any values. I just get back "0 rows selected".

```
$get_instruc = "Select * FROM TABLE(Navi_Instructions_Final.Get_Navi_Instructions_Final(:start_node_final,:end_node_final))";
```

(Strings are binded in using oci_bind_by_name).

I really do not understand how it is not working, the select statement works in SQL_Developer, so its not the PL/SQL procedure or the statement. The values initially had spaces which I have replaced with underscores and that hasn't helped. I have used ' ' and " " around the strings. I have tried removing the bindings and just using plain strings like

```
$get_instruc = "Select * FROM TABLE(Navi_Instructions_Final.Get_Navi_Instructions_Final('Room_101','Room_120'))"
```

Am I missing something basic like Oracle cannot receive strings/varchars through PHP?? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified what is actually being passed into your function when called from your application? I would add some logging to your Oracle function and store the passed in arguments for inspection. Then test those saved arguments in your select statement in SQL Developer.

Comment: I have found the problem! too many late nights coding, i had accidentally removed a line in my PL/SQL package (enable DMBS output). So it couldn't sent anything back to the PHP. Egh, I feel silly now..